# Drupal configs location

Tags: ddev

ddev seems to be looking in 'sites/default/files/sync'(relative to the docroot) for the config files however, my d8 setup has those files in project_root/config/sync. How do I get settings.ddev.php to point to the correct directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

;tldr: Set $config_directories[CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY] in your settings.php and settings.ddev.php won't do anything.

ddev only uses that as a fallback if you haven't previously set the value for your system. Please set $config_directories[CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY] in your settings.php and this should work out. settings.ddev.php does only this, which sets sync to a default value if it has not already been set (normally in settings.php):

```
// This specifies the default configuration sync directory.
if (empty($config_directories[CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY])) {
  $config_directories[CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY] = 'sites/default/files/sync';
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was the ticket.

Comment: @Dillon would you mind editing the title to something more descriptive? Maybe "How can I set the Drupal 8 config sync directory when using ddev?"

Comment: @rfay My installation is a multi-site and uses config_split. I confess I don't fully understand the D8 config system nor config_split, but I've found that if I remove this snippet from settings.ddev.php then everything works fine. If I leave it in, my "drush cim" is very confused, whether or not I've got `$settings['config_sync_directory']` set. I know I can version the ddev.settings.php, but hardcoding all those IPs/ports seems dangerous to me. Any tips?

Comment: You can override *anything* that settings.ddev.php might do in your settings.php file. So it's far easier to just add whatever setting you want in settings.php *after* the include of settings.ddev.php. If you have settings.local.php set up, you can also do it there as long as settings.local.php is included *after* settings.ddev.php.

Comment: @rfay Thanks! Adding `unset($settings['config_sync_directory']);` right after the inclusion of the settings.ddev.php file resolved it for me.